# Java: Using multiple Threads to paint simultaniously on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, multithreading

I have a JPanel on which I wish to have several threads painting "animations" on. An "animation" consists of a JLabel with an ImageIcon on it, which is being moved from one area of the screen to another area.

Now, problem is - I want several such animations to be portrayed on screen by those threads mentioned. Problem is - the JPanel's "paint()" method can only be trigged by one thread at a time - causing the animations to execute serially, instead of in a parallel way.

Any idea how to have several such animations on screen at the same time?

Answer (score 5):

It is impossible to use multiple threads to do what you want. Swing Toolkit is single threaded 
. The correct way to do it is to use one of the animation frameworks available:

- [Trident animation framework](https://github.com/kirill-grouchnikov/trident)
- [TimingFramework](https://github.com/akuhtz/timingframework)

Comment: Fixed links: [Trident animation framework](https://github.com/kirill-grouchnikov/trident), [TimingFramework](https://github.com/akuhtz/timingframework)   _(apparently too many edit requests queued to be able to edit this directly)_

Answer (score 3):

Swing is not thread-safe, thus it's simply not a supported use-case to do UI-related stuff from several threads simultaneously.

Go for the model-view-controller (MVC) pattern:

- Let all threads update a (thread safe) model.
- Whenever there is an update of the model, invoke repaint.
- repaint() will schedule the UI-thread to call the proper paint-methods.
- The paint-method should then simply read the state of the model, and draw the component accordingly.